# PHPUnit testing in PhpStorm token mismatch exception

Tags: laravel, phpunit, phpstorm

I am running unit testing on a **Laravel** project through **PhpStorm inbuilt test environment**. I am getting **token mismatch exception**.

All the configurations are correct and it was working fine. Suddenly this error showed up. I tried with the terminal and it works fine. I am developing this projects under Vagrant.

What can I do to solve this issue?

I googled and found out that changing Laravel's VerifyCsrfToken as below will solve this issue. But I need this to be default as well.
 `$except = ['/*']`

Comment: Try [Disabling Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#disabling-middleware) in your tests. I woudn't add `$except = ['/*']` as it will disable it for all routes... or you could pass the csrf token with the call `$this->call('POST', '/your-route', ['_token' => csrf_token(), ...]);`

Comment: @LazyOne - Thanks It worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem, i fixed it by setting the "Default configuration file" option in the chosen "Test Frameworks" to the phpunit.xml in my project root. It seems PHPStorm by default uses a 'local' phpunit config. I came to this idea while checking the runningUnitTests() method in Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;

and seeing dat APP_ENV was "local" and not "testing" as specified in my PHPunit.xml

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used WithoutMiddleware trait in my testing class. It worked fine. And I tried @Lijubadr 's reply also. It worked too. thank you.